# how to set "Show output from: Tests" to the default option in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, testing, output

We are doing a lot of test runs in Visual Studio and we don't want to switch all the time to "Tests" in the dropdown menu Ouput window when running some tests. Is there an option and how to set the "Tests" option to default and not "Build"?

When starting some tests it switches back to "Build". The subsequent manual selection of the Tests option should be avoided or automated.

[image]